# Error when inserting datetime into SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am having a problem inserting a datetime into SQL. my statement is...

```
INSERT INTO `booking.com`.`last_sign_in` (`personID`, `browser`, 
`deviceType`, `deviceOS`, `location`, `time`) VALUES ('1', 'chrome 
61', 'desktop', 'windows 10', 'Belfast', '20171114 10:34:09 AM');
```

When I try to run this insert statement I get the error...

[image]

all help appreciated!!

Comment: 2017-11-14 10:34:09 AM. Also not sure but doubt that AM should be there.

Comment: Use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted dates (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) or you may get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `booking.com`.`last_sign_in` (`personID`, `browser`, `deviceType`, `deviceOS`, `location`, `time`)
VALUES (1, 'chrome 61', 'desktop', 'windows 10', 'Belfast', '2017-11-14 10:34:09');
```

The dates have been changed to the correct format (dashes added and the AM removed) also, it looks like you're trying to add the string value '1' into the PersonID column which I am assuming is int so I have changed that to an int value based on that assumption